# How to find first common data in two columns of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with two columns. Each column contains a list of integers.
I want to find the FIRST value in common.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [[1,2,3,5], [3,4,5]], 'col2': [[2,3,4], [3,5]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

           col1       col2
0  [1, 2, 3, 5]  [2, 3, 4]
1     [3, 4, 5]     [3, 5]
```

Expecting a df containing for each rows the first data in common:

```
d = {'result': [2,3]}
expect_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   result
0       2
1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop here. One option with a list comprehension, and a `set` as reference in a generator expression with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
out = pd.DataFrame([next((x for x in a if x in b), None)
                    for a, b in zip(df['col1'],
                                    df['col2'].apply(set))
                    ], columns=['result'], index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
   result
0       2
1       3
```

##### as a new column

```
df['common'] = [next((x for x in a if x in b), None)
                for a, b in zip(df['col1'],
                              df['col2'].apply(set))]
```

Output:

```
           col1       col2  common
0  [1, 2, 3, 5]  [2, 3, 4]       2
1     [3, 4, 5]     [3, 5]       3
```

##### timing of the proposed solutions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterrows and numpy.intersect1d:

```
import numpy as np

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    intersect = np.intersect1d(row.col1, row.col2)
    if len(intersect) > 0:
        first = np.min(intersect)
    else:
        first = None
    df.at[index, "col"] = first
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) routine:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x['col1'], x['col2'],
                                        return_indices=False)[0], axis=1)\
      .to_frame('result')
```

---

```
   result
0       2
1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and define a `function` that returns the first common item in two list:

```
def first_common(x):
    for i in x['col1']:
        if i in x['col2']:
            return i

expected_df = df.apply(first_common, axis=1) # axis=1 applies function by rows
expected_df = expected_df.to_frame('results') # Make series to dataframe
```

`expected_df` is now:

```
   results
0        2
1        3
```

You can do the following if you want to add the result back into the original dataframe:

```
df['common'] = expected_df
```

`df` is now:

```
           col1       col2  common
0  [1, 2, 3, 5]  [2, 3, 4]       2
1     [3, 4, 5]     [3, 5]       3
```